# Trouble with variables in arcsin

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to see if the ODE - $ \pi y'=4x\arcsin(\frac{y}{x^2+1})$ has a solution through $y(0) = 0$ and if that solution is the only one to that ODE.
I've been trying to replace the $\frac{y}{x^2+1}$ inside the $arcsin$ with $z$ and the $y'$ with $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and to do integration from there but I'm getting stuck after that.

Comment: Consider that the vast majority of the non-linear differential equations that aren't solvable by separation of variables are not solvable.

Comment: I didn't learn direction field plot. As for the initial condition - isn't the way to solve the whole problem is to use the initial condition last?  Sorry but I'm just beginning with ODE's

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Gonçalo suggested, $y=0$ is a solution to the Cauchy problem. It remains to verify if it's unique, and yes, it is.

The function $F(x,y)=-\frac{4}{\pi}x\arcsin\left(\frac{y}{x^2+1}\right)$ has a partial derivative $\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial y}$ that isn't defined only in $(x,y)=(0,1)$, therefore there exists a rectangle around $(x,y)=(0,0)$ where $F$ is continuous and differentiable w.r.t $y$, so locally Lipschitz in the second variable $y$ (by Lagrange theorem), and therefore we can apply Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem to get that $y=0$ is the only solution.

**Edit:**

The derivative of $F$ w.r.t. $y$ cannot be bounded in the whole plane $\mathbb{R}^2$, but remember that Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem only requires $F$ to be *locally Lipschitz* in a neighbourhood of $P$, where $P$ is the point given by the Cauchy problem.

Now, finding precise values to bound the derivative analitically is correct, but usually not easy at all, and always tedious. It is more common to say that, if the derivative is defined in the point corresponding to the Cauchy problem, in this case $(0,0)$, then there is a neighbourhood $R\subset \mathbb{R}^2$, arbitrarily small but it must exist, where the function $F$ is both continuous and differentiable (obviously $F$ must be continuous in that point, but in this specific case there is no problem with continuity of $F$).

Now, fix $x$ and consider $F(x,y)$ as a function of $y$ only. Since is continuous and differentiable in $R$ we can use Lagrange's theorem:
$$||F(x,y_1)-F(x,y_2)||\le |\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(x,\xi)|\cdot ||(x,y_1)-(x,y_2)|| $$
for every $(x,y)$ in $R$,
with $(x, \xi)$ a point in $R$. Therefore our function $F$ is locally Lipschitz in the variable $y$ inside $R$, and we are allowed to use Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem.

Comment: Ty for the answer , I still have one problem to solve the question. I'm trying to prove the Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem by trying to bound the derivative by y of f(x,y). But can it be bound if the derivative is (4/pi)*(1/sqrt((x^2 +1)^2)-y^2) ?

Comment: @Halo added some details to make it clearer

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

> I've been trying to replace the $yx2+1$ inside the arcsin with $z$ and the $y′$ with dydx and to do integration from there but I'm getting stuck after that.

$$\pi y'=4x\arcsin\left(\frac{y}{x^2+1}\right)$$
Substitute $u=x^2+1$
$$2x\pi \dfrac {dy}{du}=4x\arcsin \left(\frac{y}u\right)$$
$$\pi \dfrac {dy}{du}=2\arcsin \left(\frac{y}u\right)$$
Then the DE is homogeneous so substitute $y=tu$ and $y'=t'u+t$:
$$t'u+t=\dfrac 2 {\pi}\arcsin t$$
The DE is separable.
But you need that:
$$\dfrac 2 {\pi}\arcsin t -t \ne 0$$
$$t \ne 0 \implies y\ne 0$$

---

I added this just to show that the DE is indeed separable but you are certainly asked to use the theorem of existence as shown in Zima's nice answer.